# It does not appear that this machine is part of an Office Online Server farm

Tags: office-online-server

In the OWA machine, I run the following PS line: `(Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm).Machines`

and I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm).Machines
Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm : It does not appear that this machine is part of an Office Online Server farm.
At line:1 char:2
+ (Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm).Machines
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotJoinedToFarm.AgentManagerNotRunning,Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Administration.GetFarmCommand
```

My ex-colleague used to solve this issue just by restarting the servers. This issue keeps reoccurring and I want to fine a solution.
Any idea where to look?

**Update 1**

I have restarted the server and now it is showing correctly. I see that there have been updates on the server, today and yesterday.

However, the updates settings are set to: Download updates but let me choose whether to install them.

Looking at the print screen below there have been updates installed. I have not installed them. There might be someone else, or they are installed automatically. Strange!

[image]

**Update 2**

After restarting the servers, users are getting the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an update has automatically installed and requires a restart to get applied!

---

**Actually,** the automatic update is not supported, you should stop it on the Online server.

**What should you do now?**

- Stop the automatic update.
- Check the latest update installed.
- Check the logs to trace the issue.
- Restart the server to temporary solve the issue.
- Run `(Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm).Machines`
- If it did not list any machine, try to re-add it again

  ```
  New-OfficeWebAppsFarm -ExternalUrl "https://office.contoso.com" -CertificateName "Office Server Cert" -EditingEnabled:$true
  ```

Comment: @M El-Q, I have updated my post above. Please read update 1.